# Custom styled component in React native with inline styles

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have a custom Text component that is a React native text component its getting wrapped in styled components but I also wanted the ability to inline style it if needed. But when I try to add the inline style of padding i get an error

```
JSON value of "100px" of type NSString cannot be converted to AB144_0_0YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix
```

Usage of component

```
<Text style={{padding: "100px"}}>some custom text</Text>
```

Custom Text Component

```
    import React, { FC } from "react";
    import styled from "styled-components/native";
    import { Text as NativeText } from "react-native";
    
    interface IText {
      type?: string | undefined;
      style?: Record<string, any>;
    }
    
    const Text: FC<IText> = ({ children, type, ...props }) => {
      console.log("props = ", props);
      return (
        <StyledText type={type} {...props}>
          {children}
        </StyledText>
      );
    };
    
    const fontType: Record<string, any> = {
      bold: "Roboto-Bold",
      italic: "Roboto-Italic",
      light: "Roboto-Light",
      medium: "Roboto-Medium",
    };
    
    const StyledText = styled(NativeText)<IText>`
      font-family: ${(props) =>
        props.type ? fontType[props.type] : props.theme.fonts.default};
      font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontSizes.default};
    `;
    
    export default Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need put the value as string for px. That's just needed for % or pt. Like mention in your error.

> Did you forget the % or pt suffix

Here the code

```
<Text style={{padding: 100}}> some custom text </Text>
```

Comment: Ah thank you I thought I tried that but I guess I didn't :). This way you can't use shorthand padding: 100 0 20 10. you would have to set each paddingTop paddingRight separately right ?